# How to specify to install libraries to /usr/local/

Tags: compiling, make

I'm trying to configure and install an application and library package. The package is [this](https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2). I followed the instructions and it installed fine, and I'm able to run the binary from the `src` directory, to where it installed.

Now I wanted to install a set of libraries by appending `--enable-asio-lib` i.e. I ran 
`./configure --enable-asio-lib`. I had already installed the required dependencies and there were no errors.

However, when I check /usr/local/lib or /usr /local/include, there are no files present. What do I have to do to make `./configure` install the libraries (and possibly the binaries) in the regular place where these files are normally installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

or in your case

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-asio-lib
```

It will install in the `/usr/local` directory tree i.e. in `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc ...

Comment: That's the standard way. Have you tested in this particular case? Because `/usr/local/` is the default prefix in `configure`

Answer (score 1):

The standard prefix in `configure` is `/usr/local`.

Install the tool `checkinstall`:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

and follow this steps:

```
git clone git@github.com:tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git
cd nghttp2
autoreconf -i
automake
autoconf

# with asio-lib
./configure --enable-asio-lib
make
```

Install with

```
make install
```

or `checkinstall` for a deb package:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

There is one warning during the installation:

```
*** Warning: The package version "0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV
0.7.15-DEV" is not a
```

If you see that, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> and type eg:

```
0.7.15
```

After the package is installed.

Here is a list of all installed files:

```
/usr
/usr/local
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/include/nghttp2
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2.h
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_client.h
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/nghttp2.h
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/nghttp2ver.h
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2.a
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2.la
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2.so
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2.so.5
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2.so.5.8.3
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.a
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.la
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.so
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libnghttp2_asio.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libnghttp2.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libnghttp2_asio.pc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nghttp2.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_nghttp2-0.7.15_DEV-py2.7.egg-info
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/doc
/usr/local/share/doc/nghttp2
/usr/local/share/doc/nghttp2/README.rst
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/h2load.1.gz
/usr/local/share/man/man1/nghttp.1.gz
/usr/local/share/man/man1/nghttpd.1.gz
/usr/local/share/man/man1/nghttpx.1.gz
/usr/local/share/nghttp2
/usr/local/share/nghttp2/fetch-ocsp-response
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/INSTALL
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/README
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/README.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/.gitignore
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/Makefile
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/Makefile.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/README.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/__init__.py
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/breadcrumbs.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/footer.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/layout.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/layout_old.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/search.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/searchbox.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/badge_only.css
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/badge_only.css.map
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/theme.css
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/theme.css.map
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/Inconsolata-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/Inconsolata.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/js
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/js/modernizr.min.js
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/js/theme.js
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/theme.conf
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme/versions.html
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/asio_http2.h.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/asio_http2.h.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/asio_http2_client.h.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/asio_http2_client.h.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/asio_http2_server.h.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/asio_http2_server.h.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/bash_completion
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/bash_completion/h2load
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/bash_completion/make_bash_completion.py
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/bash_completion/nghttp
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/bash_completion/nghttpd
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/bash_completion/nghttpx
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/building-android-binary.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/building-android-binary.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/conf.py
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/conf.py.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/contribute.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/contribute.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/h2load-howto.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/h2load-howto.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/h2load.1
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/h2load.1.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/h2load.h2r
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/index.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/index.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/libnghttp2_asio.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/libnghttp2_asio.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/make.bat
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/mkapiref.py
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp.1
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp.1.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp.h2r
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp2.h.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp2.h.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp2ver.h.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttp2ver.h.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpd.1
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpd.1.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpd.h2r
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpx-howto.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpx-howto.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpx.1
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpx.1.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/nghttpx.h2r
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/package_README.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/package_README.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/programmers-guide.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/python-apiref.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/python-apiref.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/building-android-binary.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/contribute.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/h2load-howto.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/index.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/libnghttp2_asio.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/nghttpx-howto.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/python-apiref.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/tutorial-client.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/tutorial-hpack.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/sources/tutorial-server.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/tutorial-client.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/tutorial-client.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/tutorial-hpack.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/tutorial-hpack.rst.in
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/tutorial-server.rst
/usr/share/doc/nghttp2/doc/tutorial-server.rst.in
```

Answer (score 0):

For the nghttp2 asio you need to use the following commands

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-boost=<provide-path-of-boost-root> --enable-asio-lib
```